# Andriod jquery DateTime not impactng correctly if we set another time zone in mobile (Android 7.0 or greater), Need Reason and solution

Tags: javascript, html, xamarin

I am creating a javascript project with xamarin visual studio .

Issue >> (Android 7.0 or greater)
Let my Current time Zone is EST +530 and time is 1:31Am .. now I changes my time zone as EDT (-5) then mobile time is 3:02 PM of previus date .

But when I check this time in to my android javascipt page in to mobile . It is not showing correctly . It is showing 1:31 AM while It should be 3:03 PM ..

Please help me where is the issue , issue is in the mobile  or application .

Regards, 
Lochan

Comment: Please help me if some understand my question and having some clue on it

Comment: If any one have android application in which Timezone change impact at once if we change mobile time zone datetime .. Android 7.0 version ..